# ms access create an constant on load

Tags: vba, ms-access, constants

I have an ms access database I need to run in different computers. My problem is that each computer is store the backend in different location. Until now, I only have 2 machines running, but know I need to run it in more. I stored the location of each computer in a Public Constant and with a simple If statement it was linking in the correct one.

```
 Public Const strFolderDatabasePc1 as string "c:\DatabasePc1"
 Public Const strFolderDatabasePc2 as string "c:\DatabasePc2" 
 ....
```

Is it possible to create a Public Const with an if statement on database load?

```
 Public Const strFolderDatabase as string
 If Pc1 then
    strFolderDatabase = FolderPc1
 else if Pc2 then
    strFolderDatabase = FolderPc2
 else if Pc3 then
    strFolderDatabase = FolderPc3
 else 
    strError
 EndIf
```

Thank you.

UPDATE:

Until now i have write the following code. It contains 4 Users.

```
 'Database Folders
 Public Const MainFolder As String = "\\localhost\c$\User\Main"
 Public Const UserAFolder As String = "\\localhost\c$\User\UserA"
 Public Const UserBFolder As String = "\\localhost\c$\User\UserB"
 Public Function AdminFolder() As String
 AdminFolder = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Admin\"
 End Function

 'Database Keys
 Public Const MainUserKey As String = "\\localhost\c$\User\Main\Key.txt"
 Public Const UserAKey As String = "\\localhost\c$\User\UserA\key.txt"
 Public Const UserBKey As String = "\\localhost\c$\User\UserB\key.txt"
 Public Function AdminKey() As String
 AdminFolder = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Admin\key.txt"
 End Function

 Public Function FolderExists(ByVal path_ As String) As Boolean
 On Error Resume Next
 FolderExists = (GetAttr(path_) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory
 On Error GoTo 0
 End Function

 Public Function FileExists(ByVal path_ As String) As Boolean
 On Error Resume Next
 FileExists = (Len(Dir(path_)) > 0)
 On Error GoTo 0
 End Function

 Public Function FolderDatabase()
 If FileExists(AdminKey) And FolderExists(AdminFolder) Then
      'Admin
      FolderDatabase = AdminFolder
 ElseIf FileExists(MainUserKey) And FolderExists(UserMainFolder) Then
      'MainUser
      FolderDatabase = UserMainFolder
 ElseIf FileExists(UserAKey) And FolderExists(UserAFolder) Then
      'UserA
      FolderDatabase = UserAFolder
 ElseIf FileExists(UserBKey) And FolderExists(UserBFolder) Then
      'UserB
      FolderDatabase = UserBFolder
 Else
      'Unknown User
      'Do something else...
 End If
 End Function
```

And using the following code inside each form.

```
 Sub Check()
 If FolderExists(FolderDatabase) Then
      '===> User, Continue Loading.
      If Dir(FolderDatabase & "*.*") = "" Then
           '===> Empty Folder.
           'Do something...
      Else
           '===> Files On Folder.
           'Do something...
      End If
 Else
      '===> Not Known User.
      Application.Quit acQuitSaveNone
 End If
 End Sub
```

Can I write it or do it with more simple way? Thank you.

PS:
I need to have in one place the location of each USER because I might change in the future the location or file name. Also I am using two more folders with different names and again I am using all the above.

Comment: Or just make `strFolderDatabase` a variable.

Comment: You have changed the scenario completely. First you had the application running on _multiple computers_ with one user each, now you have _one computer_ with multiple users. Please edit your question to reflect the true scenario.

Comment: Thxs for your reply. It is 4 different computers or more in the future. Each one has a different location where database is located. For example reason I write "\\localhost\c$\User\....".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense. Each computer has its own `C:` drive, that the others won't see.

So you can simply use:

```
Public Const strFolderDatabasePc As string "c:\DatabasePc"
```

That said, you might be better off to use a folder under `C:\Users\Public` as your database file isn't, as seen by Windows, an application but a *document*.

Answer (score 2):

In simple words no, but you could have a Function return the correct path by passing the pc number as argument:

```
Public Const strFolderDatabasePc1 as string "c:\DatabasePc1"
Public Const strFolderDatabasePc2 as string "c:\DatabasePc2" 

Public Function FolderDatabase(ByVal pcNo As Long) As String
    Select Case pcNo
        Case 1:
            FolderDatabase = strFolderDatabasePc1
        Case 2:    
            FolderDatabase = strFolderDatabasePc2
    End Select
 End Function
```

Then just pass the pc number required:

```
Dim path_ As String
    path_ = FolderDatabase(1)
```

To make it more readable, setup an `Enum` for the various pc's.

```
Public Enum Computers
    Home
    Work
End Enum

Public Function FolderDatabase(ByVal pc As Computers) As String
    Select Case pc
        Case Computers.Home:
            FolderDatabase = strFolderDatabasePc1
        Case Computers.Work:    
            FolderDatabase = strFolderDatabasePc2
    End Select
End Function


Dim path_ As String
    path_ = FolderDatabase(Computers.Home)
```